# Twilio: how to add name to media while sending message?

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using npm module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twilio/conversations

I'm sending media with below code:

```
props.conversationProxy.sendMessage({
  contentType: event.target.files.files[0].type,
  filename:event.target.files.files[0].name,
  media: event.target.files.files[0]
});
```

I have tried below for file names, but nothing works

```
file_name:event.target.files.files[0].name,

fileName:event.target.files.files[0].name,

FileName:event.target.files.files[0].name, 

file:event.target.files.files[0].name, 

name:event.target.files.files[0].name
```

getting below from twilio:

```
{ 
contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
​​
filename: null
​​
sid: "MEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
​​
size: 4697
}
```

I want to send media with filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The SDK docs show that the [options you can pass when sending media through the Conversations SDK](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/conversations/releases/1.2.3/docs/Conversation.html#SendMediaOptions) (the `Conversation#SendMediaOptions`) are:

```
Name        | Type          | Description
------------|---------------|----------------------
contentType | String        | content type of media
media       | String/Buffer | content to post
```

`filename` is not an option, so you cannot pass it to the SDK.

According to [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/media-support-conversations#javascript), you can set the filename by providing the data as a `FormData` object:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
formData.append('filename', event.target.files[0].filename);
formData.append('contentType', event.target.files[0].type);

channel.sendMessage(formData);
```

I haven't tested this, but hopefully it works.

Comment: so is there any way to add name to media?

Comment: I think you need to pass it as FormData, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get file name is

```
event.target.files[0].filename
```

Comment: i'm getting filename properly with "event.target.files.files[0].name,",

Comment: i have tried the static filename as well.. but it still not working